# About QR decomposition

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

While studying matrix QR decomposition I've found the following:

[image]

I understand the general idea. But, in the Proof, $A = (a_1, ..., a_n)$. What are $a_1, ..., a_n$? They are elements of matrix $A$? Why they are not written as $a_{ij}, ...$?

Comment: Columns of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

They are the column vectors of the matrix $A$.

Comment: Ok. I remember seeing references to columns written as $\alpha_i$. So, in general, should I think $a_i$ refers to columns and $a_{ij}$ refers to elements?

Comment: Yes that's right. In fact, $a_{ij}$ is the $j$-th element of the $i$-th column vector, which is the same as the $ij$-th matrix element.